# CakePHP 2: Authentification by multiple fields (either email or phone no)

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I have authentification system that allow login by email or phone number. How I can write custom `scope`, that will set `username` field to `email` if it contain `@` and if not to `phone` ?

```
'authenticate' => array(
    'FormExtended' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password',
        ),
        'scope' => array(
            'User.active' => true,
        ),
    )
)
```

Can this be done with scope condition ?

Comment: Is `FormExtended` a custom authentication object? If yes, you can achieve this within  `FormExtendedAuthenticate::authenticate()`.